# Updating a table with a MAX based calculation from another table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I created a table (Attendance) to store calculations, and I am updating the table to fill in the majority of the computations. I need to figure out when an employee (EMP_NB) left work for the day. This is calculated by `TIMEDIFF(ADDTIME(PERIOD, '1:00'), SEC_TO_TIME(Activity_Secs))`.

My issue is that I can't figure out a way to grab the MAX(PERIOD) per EMP_NB per DATE, while also grabbing the corresponding Activity_Secs.

**tableA**

```
╭────────┬──────┬────────┬───────────────╮
│ EMP_NB │ DATE │ Period │ Activity_Secs │
╰────────┴──────┴────────┴───────────────╯
```

Here is the MySQL code I made to get the first period an employee logged in.

```
UPDATE calc_Attendance AS att, tableA AS a
JOIN (
        SELECT 
        EMP_NB,
        DATE,
        Period,
        Activity_Secs
        FROM tableA
        GROUP BY EMP_NB, DATE, Period
    ) m
ON a.EMP_NB = m.EMP_NB and a.DATE = m.DATE and a.Period = m.Period
SET DEPTARTURE_ACTUAL = TIMEDIFF(ADDTIME(m.Period, '1:00'), SEC_TO_TIME(m.Activity_Secs))
WHERE att.EMP_NB = m.EMP_NB AND att.DATE = m.DATE
;
```

Any help will be appreciated. I don't have a lot of experience with SQL so this is driving me insane.

Comment: You are not grouping Activity_Secs in ur query. DO u want to take the max value of this col?

Comment: I need the Activity_Secs that is in the same row as MAX(PERIOD) per EMP_NB per DATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE calc_Attendance AS att, tableA AS a
JOIN (
        SELECT 
        EMP_NB,
        DATE,
        MAX(Period) AS Period,
        Activity_Secs
        FROM tableA
        GROUP BY EMP_NB,DATE,Activity_Secs
    ) m
ON a.EMP_NB = m.EMP_NB and a.DATE = m.DATE and a.Period = m.Period
SET DEPTARTURE_ACTUAL = TIMEDIFF(ADDTIME(m.Period, '1:00'), SEC_TO_TIME(m.Activity_Secs))
WHERE att.EMP_NB = m.EMP_NB AND att.DATE = m.DATE
;
```

Comment: Your code worked when I changed: `GROUP BY EMP_NB,DATE,Activity_Secs` to `GROUP BY EMP_NB,DATE`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are u talking about the Inner SELECT query?

Comment: Yes. When it was also grouped by `Activity_Secs` I would get random times throughout the day. Without it, I get only the max time.

Comment: I think this might have a small issue that the Activity_Secs might not be from the same row as MAX(Period)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on the purpose of `tableA` in your query, but I think that the following should work.

```
UPDATE calc_Attendance AS att
JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT EMP_NB, DATE, Period, Activity_Secs
        FROM tableA
        ORDER BY Period DESC
    ) m1
    GROUP BY EMP_NB, DATE
) m
ON att.EMP_NB = m.EMP_NB and att.DATE = m.DATE
SET DEPTARTURE_ACTUAL = TIMEDIFF(ADDTIME(m.Period, '1:00'), SEC_TO_TIME(m.Activity_Secs));
```